# Configuring Grails application to use ClearDB/MySQL on Heroku

Tags: mysql, grails, heroku, add-on

I have a Grails (2.0.0) application and have successfully:

1. Deployed it to Heroku using the H2 database
2. Configured it to use a local MySQL database
3. Added the ClearDB addon

However, I get a HTTP 503 error when I try to run the application while attempting to use the ClearDB instance.

Here are snippets from DataSource.groovy (a combination of tricks from various posts, including [this tutorial from ClearDB](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/grails#set_up_the_database) and [this help page from Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/grails#set_up_the_database))

```
dataSource {
  pooled = true
  driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}
```

...

```
production {        
  dataSource {
    dbCreate = "update"
      uri = new URI(System.env.DATABASE_URL?:"mysql://99784530f103:934c2a0@server.cleardb.com/heroku_0ac7f6f45fa34")
      url = "jdbc:mysql://"+uri.host+uri.path
      username = uri.userInfo.split(":")[0]
      password = uri.userInfo.split(":")[1]
    }
}
```

where the MySQL URL string comes from the DATABASE_URL environment variable.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Figures... Soon after I post the question, I figured it out.  Change "DATABASE_URL" to "CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL_A".  At least this is now an official Grails2.0/Heroku/ClearDB answer!